Is there a way to give an analytical result to the following integral?
I hope to obtain the analytical result of gg[r]. Is there a way to give an analytical result to the following integral of function gg[r]?
Clear["`*"]
\[Rho][r_] = \[Rho]R*(1 - k*Rs/r)^3*(rsp/r)^\[Gamma]sp;
g[r_] = Integrate[\[Rho][r]*r^2, {r, k*Rs, r1}] /. r1 -> r // Normal //
   Simplify//Expand;
gg[r_] = Integrate[(2*g[r])/(r^2 - 2*r*g[r]), r]

If that doesn't work, when this integral can be converted into a differential equation, is there a way? The differential equation is as follows:
sol = DSolve[{f'[r]/f[r] == (2*g[r])/(r^2 - 2*r*g[r])}, f[r], r]

Finally, I want to obtain the analytical result of function f[r].

@The down-voter: It's unfair to down vote without any explaining comment.

If you evaluate all the parameters, e.g. rsp = 1; Rs = Pi; k = 2; \[Gamma]sp = 5; \[Rho]R = 31/10;, then your code returns 31 (-(Log[r]/31) +     80/31 \[Pi]^2 RootSum[      3968 \[Pi]^5 - 7440 \[Pi]^4 #1 + 4960 \[Pi]^3 #1^2 -         1240 \[Pi]^2 #1^3 + 31 #1^5 - 400 \[Pi]^2 #1^6 &, (       Log[r - #1] #1^5)/(       1488 \[Pi]^4 - 1984 \[Pi]^3 #1 + 744 \[Pi]^2 #1^2 - 31 #1^4 +         480 \[Pi]^2 #1^5) &]). This is a better way than to find a generic  complicated expression.

@user64494 Thanks for your idea, this may be an alternative approach. But based on this result, it seems difficult to use in my publication. I will think about other ways, and thank you again for your help and support.

When I run your code with  few modifications, I get an analytical result (and the integrations return quickly:
There is no benefit in your definition with a pattern, so:
\[Rho]r = \[Rho]R*(1 - k*Rs/r)^3*(rsp/r)^\[Gamma]sp

If you integrate with GenerateConditions -> True, you get a result but the conditions are long.  Let's assume that the conditions are satisified:
gr = Integrate[\[Rho]r*r^2, {r, k*Rs, r1}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False]

returns an expression.
ggr = Simplify[Integrate[(2*gr)/(r^2 - 2*r*gr), r]]

also returns an expression "longish" expression that takes up three lines (LeafCount[ggr] is 171)

You forgot the bit with /. r1 -> r in the definition of gr.

I can’t check now.  Does it not integrate with your fix @azerbajdzan/

Thanks for your helps. The definition of g[r] with /.r1->r is the key to the difficulty of this question.

Simply don't do the definite integrals. Process the indefinite integrals as list of their boundary values
  Integrate[\[Rho][r]*r^2, r] // FullSimplify

$$\text{$\rho $R} \left(\frac{\text{rsp}}{r}\right)^{\text{$\gamma $sp}} \left(\frac{k^3 \text{Rs}^3}{\text{$\gamma $sp}}-\frac{3 k^2 r \text{Rs}^2}{\text{$\gamma $sp}-1}+\frac{3 k r^2 \text{Rs}}{\text{$\gamma $sp}-2}+\frac{r^3}{3-\text{$\gamma $sp}}\right)$$
 g[r_] = ((r^3/(3 - \[Gamma]sp) + (3 k r^2 Rs)/(-2 + \[Gamma]sp) - (
 3 k^2 r Rs^2)/(-1 + \[Gamma]sp) + (
 k^3 Rs^3)/\[Gamma]sp ) /. {{r -> r}, {r -> k*Rs}})

$$\left\{\frac{k^3 \text{Rs}^3}{\text{$\gamma $sp}}-\frac{3 k^2 r \text{Rs}^2}{\text{$\gamma $sp}-1}+\frac{3 k r^2 \text{Rs}}{\text{$\gamma $sp}-2}+\frac{r^3}{3-\text{$\gamma $sp}}, \quad \frac{k^3 \text{Rs}^3}{3-\text{$\gamma $sp}}+\frac{3 k^3 \text{Rs}^3}{\text{$\gamma $sp}-2}-\frac{3 k^3 \text{Rs}^3}{\text{$\gamma $sp}-1}+\frac{k^3 \text{Rs}^3}{\text{$\gamma $sp}}\right\}$$
  FullSimplify@Subtract @@ Integrate[(2*g[r])/(r^2 - 2*r*g[r]), r]

  12 k^3 Rs^3 (Log[r]/(12 k^3 Rs^3) - 
   Log[12 k^3 Rs^3 - 6 r \[Gamma]sp + 11 r \[Gamma]sp^2 - 
   6 r \[Gamma]sp^3 + r \[Gamma]sp^4]/(12 k^3 Rs^3)) + 
   2 (-(Log[r]/2) + 
   1/2 (-6 + 11 \[Gamma]sp - 
   6 \[Gamma]sp^2 + \[Gamma]sp^3) RootSum[-12 k^3 Rs^3 + 
    22 k^3 Rs^3 \[Gamma]sp - 12 k^3 Rs^3 \[Gamma]sp^2 + 
    2 k^3 Rs^3 \[Gamma]sp^3 + 6 \[Gamma]sp #1 - 
    36 k^2 Rs^2 \[Gamma]sp #1 - 11 \[Gamma]sp^2 #1 + 
    30 k^2 Rs^2 \[Gamma]sp^2 #1 + 6 \[Gamma]sp^3 #1 - 
    6 k^2 Rs^2 \[Gamma]sp^3 #1 - \[Gamma]sp^4 #1 + 
    18 k Rs \[Gamma]sp #1^2 - 24 k Rs \[Gamma]sp^2 #1^2 + 
    6 k Rs \[Gamma]sp^3 #1^2 - 4 \[Gamma]sp #1^3 + 
    6 \[Gamma]sp^2 #1^3 - 2 \[Gamma]sp^3 #1^3 &, 
  Log[r - #1]/(-6 + 36 k^2 Rs^2 + 11 \[Gamma]sp - 
      30 k^2 Rs^2 \[Gamma]sp - 6 \[Gamma]sp^2 + 
      6 k^2 Rs^2 \[Gamma]sp^2 + \[Gamma]sp^3 - 36 k Rs #1 + 
      48 k Rs \[Gamma]sp #1 - 12 k Rs \[Gamma]sp^2 #1 + 12 #1^2 - 
      18 \[Gamma]sp #1^2 + 6 \[Gamma]sp^2 #1^2) &])


Thanks for your help. I checked your solution and found that you seem to have missed ((rsp/r)^\[Gamma]sp)  when defining g[r]. Unfortunately, after adding it, the result still cannot be given analytically. Thank you again for your help.
